# How to mirror an Android Screen on Laptop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb, broken-screen

My Android device screen touch is not working, it's just damaged, so I have done the hard reset on it. But it still doesn't work. And now when I start the device I'm not able to proceed further from the Language Select option due to touch not working. So I need help, if someone can tell me how I can mirror my screen on laptop in this situation, if possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Chrome plugin to mirror your Android screen to your laptop:

http://www.vysor.io/

Comment: Requires (at least) debugging mode to be on, but he had already done a hard reset.

Answer (score 0):

You would need USB-Debugging for any tool that could mirror your display.
As you have reset your phone, USB-Debugging is not active.
But anyway, what do you want to achieve with a broken touch and a resetted phone?

You could restore a ROM backup where this USB-Debugging is enabled, if you had any. But even then you would need to accept the new fingerprint.

Try an OTA-cable and to use a USB-Keybord, maybe this can help a bit.